# Installing Windows 8 over Windows 7 with Ubuntu installed using wubi?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, wubi

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed using Wubi on my `D:\` drive , while Windows 7 is installed in win `C:\`. Will installing Windows 8 over Windows 7 in `C:\` render my Ubuntu installation unusable? If so: How do I install Windows 8 so that my Ubuntu installation is not affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that by using Wubi you mean that it's installed in an image inside your D drive, instead of being installed in its own partition or partition set.

If that's the case you won't have any problem upgrading to Windows 8, because Ubuntu is booted from the Windows boot menu.

This would be the procedure to do it:

1. Check that you do have the setup I described above, to do so follow these steps:
   1.1. Open an elevated command prompt in Windows.
   1.2. Execute `bcdedit /enum`, it'll output the boot menu configuration, look for something like this:

   [image: Ubuntu boot entry]

   That'd be the menu entry for Ubuntu, you can see the path to the boot code it uses, in this case it is `C:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr`. If you **don't** see an entry similar to this one in the output of the previous command then Ubuntu is not installed "inside" Windows, it's then probably installed the usual way with partitions for its own; don't continue with the procedure.
2. Within Windows, insert or mount the Windows 8 DVD or image your have and start the installation.
3. When prompted to perform an upgrade or a custom installation select to perform an upgrade, the compatibility assistant will execute.
4. If it clears you to upgrade to Windows 8 do so, the installation will begin and Windows will reboot a couple of times.
5. In one of the reboots you'll be presented with a boot menu with 3 options (default case, there may be more). One to boot Windows 8, one to rollback the upgrade and another one for Ubunut. Here click Windows 8 as the installation is not yet finished. It will take its time (quite some time actually) and after that the installation is finished.
6. After Windows is upgraded to Windows 8, Ubuntu will still show up in the boot menu and you will be able to boot it just as before; this is what you'll see:

   [image: New boot menu]

In the example Ubuntu was installed directly in the C partition, I suspect that if you have it installed in the D drive the boot code will be in D too (since everything related to the Ubuntu installation is inside a directory called "ubuntu" in the root of the drive), so you could even format C and perform a clean installation of Windows 8. Although if you do that there'll be no boot menu entry for Ubuntu after the installation so you'll have to add it using `bcdedit` so that it looks like the one that existed before (the "Real-mode Boot Sector" screenshot above).

As an example to create one like the screenshot above you'd have to do this:

1. Create a new entry:

   `bcdedit /create /d Ubuntu /application bootsector`
2. That will output an ID, which you'll need for the next steps.
3. Set the device:

   `bcdedit /set {id} device partition=C:`
4. Set the path:

   `bcdedit /set {id} path \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr`
5. Add that entry to the boot menu:

   `bcdedit /displayorder {id} /addlast`
6. Done, a `bcdedit /enum` will show you the newly created entry for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Procedures to do a Dual Boot

> Step 1: Turn on the PC and boot into Windows 8. Create a new partition for Ubuntu installation. You can create a new partition by following our how to create a new partition and how to shrink or extend a partition guides. You can also take the help of Partition Wizard (free) software for advanced task.
>
> Step 2: The next step is to download Ubuntu from this official page. Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are available. If you are unsure which one to download, simply download 32-bit Ubuntu.
>
> Step 3: To start the installation you need to have the installation media. That is, you need to either burn the Ubuntu ISO onto a DVD or create a bootable USB. We suggest you use a USB drive (2 GB+) as installing from USB is faster than DVD. If you have a USB drive, use Universal USB Installer to make the bootable USB.

Connect the USB drive to the PC, backup data from USB drive, and then follow the steps given below to create bootable Ubuntu USB:

> To create bootable Ubuntu USB:
>   a. Download Universal USB Installer from here. Run Universal USB Installer (it doesn’t require any installation).
>   b. Click I agree button on the License Agreement screen to proceed to the next step.
>
> C. Here, you will be asked to select the Linux distribution. Select Ubuntu from the drop-down list and click Browse button to browse to the Ubuntu ISO file that you have downloaded in step 2. Enable the option named Show all drives and then carefully select your USB drive letter. Finally enable Format Drive (Erase Content) option and click Create button.

[image]

> d. Your bootable Ubuntu USB should be ready within a minute.
>
> Step 4: Once you have the bootable USB, restart your PC (make sure that the USB is connected to PC). Make necessary changes to the BIOS to enable USB booting and then restart the PC again. You will see following options:

Run Ubuntu from this USB

Install Ubuntu on a Hard Disk

Test memory

Boot from first hard disk

Advanced options

Help

Select Install Ubuntu on a Hard Disk option and hit enter key.

Step 5: Within a few seconds, you will be greeted with a welcome screen where you need to select your Language. Once done, click Install Ubuntu button.
[image]

> Step 6: In the following screen, Ubuntu setup offers options to download updates (while installing) and install MP3 plugin. Select both options and click Continue button.
>   [image]
>
> Step 7: If your PC is not connected to the Internet, you will be asked to select a wireless network, if available. If you don’t have a wireless network at your place, simply select I don’t want to connect to a wi-fi network right now option and click Continue. And if you have a wi-fi network, select the network and click Continue button.

Step 8: This is the most important step of installation. If you are getting Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 8 option select that option and click Continue. On the other hand if you are getting "This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?" message, select Something else option and click Continue to proceed to Installation Type screen.
[image]

> Step 9: In the Installation Type screen, carefully select the drive that you have previously created for Ubuntu and click Delete button. You should now see free space entry. Select the free space entry and click Add button to create a Swap partition. Select Location of new partition as Beginning and then select Use as Swap. Click Ok button.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> Next, in the Installation Type screen, again select on the free space and click Add button. This time, Select location of partition as Beginning, select use as EXT4 journaling file system and finally select Mount point as "/". Click Ok button.
>
> Finally click Install Now button to start installing Ubuntu.
>
> Step 10: In the next two screens, you will be asked to select your location and keyboard layout. In the last step, you will be asked to enter login details (user name and password). Once done, you will be asked to restart the computer.
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> Step 11: Restart the computer to see the following screen:
>   [image]
>
> You may see Windows Recovery Environment option instead of Microsoft Windows 8 entry in the boot menu if you have installed Ubuntu after choosing “Something else” option in step 8. In simple words, Ubuntu 11.10 setup doesn’t recognize Windows 8 and adds Windows 8 entry as Windows Recovery Environment (or, at least, this is what I got when I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in dual boot with Windows 8 Developer Preview build).
>
> Simply select Microsoft Windows or Windows Recovery Environment entry to boot into Windows 8. To boot into Ubuntu select Ubuntu with Linux.

Comment: Yash stated that his Ubuntu installation was done by Wubi, not installed in a partition or set of partitions. Your answer doesn't apply to this question, since he wants to upgrade his Windows installation not install Ubuntu again for a regular dual boot environment.