# Installing Windows 8 over Windows 7 with Ubuntu installed using wubi (both on `C:\`)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, wubi, windows-8-upgrade

**Current state** I'm using both - Ubuntu (installed via Wubi on the same drive as Windows) and Windows 7 - quite frequently. I just bought the upgrade to Windows 8 and was curious to try it out, however I'm quite insecure whether Windows 8's "secure boot" will exclude my current Ubuntu installation and if it's even possible to keep it.

**So...** is there any way to upgrade to Windows 8 *without* overwriting Ubuntu? (I really don't want to reinstall it, as a lot of customization has been done here and taking backups and all would get pretty wearing (same case for Windows 7 - if possible, I'd like to keep my files))

---

This is not a dublicate of [Installing Windows 8 over Windows 7 with Ubuntu installed using wubi?](https://superuser.com/questions/499861/installing-windows-8-over-windows-7-with-ubuntu-installed-using-wubi) because this question only deals with the case when Ubuntu has been installed on (e.g.) `D:\` (while Windows is being installed on `C:\`)

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of the previous question because it does not matter if Ubuntu is installed on C:\ or D:\  In fact, in the accepted *answer*, Ubuntu is installed via wubi on C:\  That answer gives the steps to properly upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8, retaining the wubi installed Ubuntu.

Comment: But in the answer he only writes about the D:\ drive - I don't get it :(
 > ...you mean that it's installed in an image inside your D drive...If that's the case...[long answer 1]
 > In the example Ubuntu was installed directly in the C partition, I suspect that if you have it installed in the D drive the boot code will be in D too...[long answer 2]
In both cases he refers to the fact, that something is on the `D:\` drive - I don't even have one!

Comment: Hi, I'm the one who wrote that answer, I detailed the procedure answering the original question where Ubuntu was installed in the `D` drive; that's why I mention `D`. As PJC says the installation I had in the virtual machine was actually done in `C`, you don't even have to have a `D` drive. Just follow the steps 1-6 below "This would be the procedure to do it:"

Comment: @peat-ar "In the example Ubuntu was installed directly in the C partition..." - so, the solution given was for Ubuntu in C:\, which is your case.  The *question* was about D:\ but the solution given was for C:\ (though it should work identically for D:\).

Comment: Ok, sry for the misunderstanding - thx a lot :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Windows 8 over Windows 7 with Ubuntu installed using wubi?](http://superuser.com/questions/499861/installing-windows-8-over-windows-7-with-ubuntu-installed-using-wubi)